# Trouble with sound detection

Tags: raspbian, python, audio

I am trying to see how long it takes `pygame.mixer.music.play()` to actually initialize a sound. I have an audio cord running out the 3.5 jack back into the Pi through a USB soundcard. I think the code I have should, in theory, work but I am still fairly new to Python and `pyaudio`. It ignores input entirely right now, I can have the audio disconnected and it still returns a time.

```
import pygame
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import os
import pyaudio

FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100
CHUNK = 1024
THRESHOLD = 500

pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 1, 370)
pygame.mixer.init()

while True:

    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    stream = p.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE, input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)


    data = stream.read(CHUNK)

    print "recording..."

    Sound_Start = time.time()
    print 'Music Command Started:',Sound_Start

    pygame.mixer.music.play(1,0.0) 

    if data > THRESHOLD:
        Sound_Finish = time.time()
        print 'Music Command Finished:', Sound_Finish
        print '-------', '\n',print Sound_Finish - Sound_Start


stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()`
```

I've tried messing with the `CHUNK` and `THRESHOLD` values but it doesn't seem to matter. What am I doing wrong here?